# Spring MVC Servlet Mapping Causing URLs to be called twice

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have the following web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>cheapig</display-name>

<!--Definição do Contexto Global do Container do Spring com recursos (beans) que são compartilhados com
TODOS os Servlets e Filtros -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Cria o container do Spring compartilhado com todos os Servlets e Filtros -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <display-name>sessionListener</display-name>
    <listener-class>br.com.cheapig.util.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Filtro para controlar acesso -->
<filter>
 <filter-name>cheapigFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>      
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>cheapigFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>

<!-- Definição do Servlet que processa todos os requests da aplicação. Como se está utilizando
o Framework Spring, o servlet é o DispatcherServlet. -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cheapig</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/cheapig/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Mapeamento dos Servlets e URLs -->     
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cheapig</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cheapig/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/view/util/layout_404.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/view/util/layout_405.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/view/util/layout_500.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

However, when I try calling for example: "http://localhost:9191/cheapig/urlMappedToAControllerMethod/" the "urlMappedToAControllerMethod" is called twice. I guess that the problem is the mapping, because, the cheapigFilter also gets called twice before forwarding to the "urlMappedToAControllerMethod".

What's wrong? And how could i fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the configuration - can you please show your controller implementation also.

Comment: Yeah. I could show. But as I told before, the Filter is called twice and due to this any controller is being called twice.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this issue?

Comment: No, not yet. I'm still trying to figure it out.